# Как правильно вставить новую запись?

Tags: python, sql, sqlite, sqlite3

В таблице два столбца имя, номер. При выполнении ошибок никаких нет, процесс заканчивается:

> Process finished with exit code 0

Но собственно никакой записи не добовляется.

```
def add_num(name, fulnum):
    with sqlite3.connect("BasePers.db") as con:
        cur = con.cursor()
        cur.execute(f"INSERT INTO persons (PersonName, PersonNumber) VALUES ('%{name}%', '%{fulnum}%')")
        con.commit()

add_num("Тема", 8981)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

попробуйте так:

```
cur.execute("INSERT INTO persons (PersonName, PersonNumber) VALUES (?,?)", (name, fulnum))
```

---

**UPD:** вот протестированный и рабочий пример:

```
name = "name"
val = 123

with sqlite3.connect(r"c:\temp\TEST.db") as con:
    cur = con.cursor()
    cur.execute("CREATE TABLE persons (PersonName VARCHAR(100), PersonNumber INTEGER)")
    sql = "INSERT INTO persons (PersonName, PersonNumber) VALUES (?, ?)"
    cur.execute(sql, (name, val))
    con.commit()
```

---

проверка:

```
In [366]: cur.execute("select * from persons")
Out[366]: <sqlite3.Cursor at 0x14e5098b180>

In [367]: list(cur.fetchall())
Out[367]: [('name', 123)]
```

Comment: Не помогло, в sqlite studio в консоли пишет это [15:41:02] База данных, переданная через аргументы командной строки (pythonProject1\BasePers.db), уже находится в списке под именем BasePers.